A lot of LWLock - SubtransSLRU occurred in running same function multiple times
We have a postgresql function called processbitupdate(xxxx),its performance is very good if I execute it once, it takes less than 1 second.
Our application has a lot of connections to the database, and each connection execute the function based on different input parameters. I saw a lot of wait_event_type: LWLock, wait_event: SubtransSLRU by running this query:
select 
  now()-query_start as runtime, 
  pid, 
  query_start, 
  wait_event, 
  wait_event_type, 
  substr(query,1,80), 
  state 
from pg_stat_activity
where state!='idle'
and query like '%processbitupdate%'
order by 1 desc;


Each pid runs very very slowly in this time.
LWLock:SubtransSLRU.
A process is waiting to access the simple least-recently used (SLRU) cache for a subtransaction.
I want to know if there is any way to improve this low performance issue?

Can you please share the source code for your processbitupdate() function?
